# Convertir código de animación de scroll de jQuery a Javascript puro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Este código permite que al hacer clic en un enlace este me lleve a la sección de la pagina web específica.

```
function smoothScroll(){
        var smoothScrollItem = $('.smoothScroll');
        smoothScrollItem.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            var seccionOffsetTop = $(href).offset().top-71;
            $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: seccionOffsetTop}, 1000);
        });
    };
    smoothScroll();
```

La cuestión es que estoy realizando una página en Javascript, pero aún no logro descifrar cómo se debe escribir.

Comment: Es tan sencillo como hacer uso de [`window.scroll({top: ..., left: ..., behavior: 'smooth'})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) y [`xxx.offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop).

Comment: Buscando en google alguien recomendo esta web [link](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) no puedo decirte si esta bien el resultado final pues desconozco de JS

Comment: Una forma sencilla podría ser que a cada sección le coloques un `id`, por ejemplo, `id="seccion-1"` y a los enlaces hagas referencias hacia él. Es decir, `<a href="#seccion-1">Ir a la sección 1</a>`. No tiene por qué llamarse **seccion-1**, pero es un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Para conseguir lo que deseas debes hacer uso de las siguientes funciones:

- [`window.scroll({top: ..., left: ..., behavior: 'smooth'})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll).
- [`HTMLElement.offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop).

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de uso:

```js
/* Ejecutamos lo necesario cuando se cargue completamente el DOM */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  /* Obtenemos todos los elementos con la clase "smoothScroll" */
  let smoothScrollItem = document.querySelectorAll('.smoothScroll');
  /* Iteramos por cada uno de ellos */
  smoothScrollItem.forEach(elemento => {
    /* Por cada elemento encontrado agregamos un evento "clic" */
    elemento.addEventListener('click', e => {
      /* Evitamos el comportamiento por defecto del enlace (salto brusco) */
      e.preventDefault();
      /* Generamos una instancia de URL a partir del campo "href"
        para obtener el "hash" (lo que va a partir del #, incluido) */
      let url = new URL(elemento.href);
      /* Hacemos scroll hasta el parte superior y restamos 71 como indicas */
      window.scroll({
        top: document.querySelector(url.hash).offsetTop - 71,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
h1 > a {
  font-size: 50%;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul id="arriba">
  <li><a href="#zona1" class="smoothScroll">Zona 1 (CON scroll suave)</a></li>
  <li><a href="#zona2" class="smoothScroll">Zona 2 (CON scroll suave)</a></li>
  <li><a href="#zona3">Zona 3 (SIN scroll suave)</a></li>
</ul>
<h1 id="zona1">Zona 1 <a href="#arriba" class="smoothScroll">arriba (CON scroll suave)</a></h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam efficitur elementum ornare. Nunc euismod tincidunt laoreet. Vestibulum id velit ac arcu mattis congue eget id sem. Morbi eget sollicitudin quam. Nulla lobortis mi eget magna luctus, eu elementum nunc rutrum. Sed tincidunt quam velit, fringilla vulputate urna sollicitudin in. Duis rhoncus viverra risus, at molestie mauris. Proin maximus consequat erat, eu maximus arcu dapibus ac. Quisque eu tristique nunc, in ultricies magna. Nullam mattis viverra justo vitae rutrum. Morbi vitae egestas justo, vel porta ex. Sed commodo malesuada cursus. Nullam maximus dolor a velit rutrum, eget auctor sem dapibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam viverra lacinia lacus id hendrerit. Pellentesque molestie volutpat tortor a iaculis.<br/>Sed mattis aliquam erat viverra suscipit. Fusce tristique orci in arcu condimentum euismod. Nunc et rutrum justo, a scelerisque lectus. In varius metus eget vulputate pharetra. Proin in mi non augue ultricies faucibus in quis lorem. Ut consectetur sit amet eros id posuere. Praesent quis tortor ut massa hendrerit dignissim a vitae lectus. Aliquam commodo lacinia enim, ut aliquet eros elementum non. Morbi laoreet vulputate eros lacinia faucibus.<br/>Phasellus faucibus nunc sit amet tortor molestie, ac sagittis nunc blandit. Aliquam suscipit nec justo ut ornare. Praesent eget urna aliquam, vehicula nisi sit amet, fringilla lacus. Nulla pharetra purus blandit, tincidunt massa et, varius quam. Mauris non purus quam. Sed vel purus elementum, cursus nibh a, semper magna. Sed justo lectus, efficitur id risus aliquam, hendrerit semper justo. Quisque hendrerit convallis sapien. Cras hendrerit ac neque quis suscipit. Sed aliquam erat quis elit tincidunt, quis commodo dui ornare. Vivamus bibendum ligula nisl, ut sollicitudin elit convallis eu.<br/>Aenean mollis ullamcorper mollis. Proin dapibus id libero mollis egestas. Morbi tincidunt mattis pulvinar. Duis ut lorem a ante consectetur malesuada. Quisque placerat eros non ex efficitur cursus. Vivamus elit mi, venenatis eu purus vitae, lacinia laoreet elit. Nullam sapien elit, sodales at odio vel, sagittis vestibulum arcu. Duis at ipsum dolor. Fusce dictum eros vel luctus posuere. Phasellus blandit ante vel leo pulvinar, a hendrerit felis viverra. Morbi elit mi, sollicitudin sit amet ante sit amet, fringilla hendrerit quam.<br/>Cras porta fermentum diam, in pretium purus volutpat lacinia. Cras id elementum ante. Sed ultricies est quis odio ultrices luctus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed vel lorem nec risus lacinia vehicula ac ultricies orci. Nulla rhoncus vehicula mollis. Vivamus porta nibh eget leo molestie, non convallis elit fermentum.</p>
<h1 id="zona2">Zona 2 <a href="#arriba" class="smoothScroll">arriba (CON scroll suave)</a></h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam efficitur elementum ornare. Nunc euismod tincidunt laoreet. Vestibulum id velit ac arcu mattis congue eget id sem. Morbi eget sollicitudin quam. Nulla lobortis mi eget magna luctus, eu elementum nunc rutrum. Sed tincidunt quam velit, fringilla vulputate urna sollicitudin in. Duis rhoncus viverra risus, at molestie mauris. Proin maximus consequat erat, eu maximus arcu dapibus ac. Quisque eu tristique nunc, in ultricies magna. Nullam mattis viverra justo vitae rutrum. Morbi vitae egestas justo, vel porta ex. Sed commodo malesuada cursus. Nullam maximus dolor a velit rutrum, eget auctor sem dapibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam viverra lacinia lacus id hendrerit. Pellentesque molestie volutpat tortor a iaculis.<br/>Sed mattis aliquam erat viverra suscipit. Fusce tristique orci in arcu condimentum euismod. Nunc et rutrum justo, a scelerisque lectus. In varius metus eget vulputate pharetra. Proin in mi non augue ultricies faucibus in quis lorem. Ut consectetur sit amet eros id posuere. Praesent quis tortor ut massa hendrerit dignissim a vitae lectus. Aliquam commodo lacinia enim, ut aliquet eros elementum non. Morbi laoreet vulputate eros lacinia faucibus.<br/>Phasellus faucibus nunc sit amet tortor molestie, ac sagittis nunc blandit. Aliquam suscipit nec justo ut ornare. Praesent eget urna aliquam, vehicula nisi sit amet, fringilla lacus. Nulla pharetra purus blandit, tincidunt massa et, varius quam. Mauris non purus quam. Sed vel purus elementum, cursus nibh a, semper magna. Sed justo lectus, efficitur id risus aliquam, hendrerit semper justo. Quisque hendrerit convallis sapien. Cras hendrerit ac neque quis suscipit. Sed aliquam erat quis elit tincidunt, quis commodo dui ornare. Vivamus bibendum ligula nisl, ut sollicitudin elit convallis eu.<br/>Aenean mollis ullamcorper mollis. Proin dapibus id libero mollis egestas. Morbi tincidunt mattis pulvinar. Duis ut lorem a ante consectetur malesuada. Quisque placerat eros non ex efficitur cursus. Vivamus elit mi, venenatis eu purus vitae, lacinia laoreet elit. Nullam sapien elit, sodales at odio vel, sagittis vestibulum arcu. Duis at ipsum dolor. Fusce dictum eros vel luctus posuere. Phasellus blandit ante vel leo pulvinar, a hendrerit felis viverra. Morbi elit mi, sollicitudin sit amet ante sit amet, fringilla hendrerit quam.<br/>Cras porta fermentum diam, in pretium purus volutpat lacinia. Cras id elementum ante. Sed ultricies est quis odio ultrices luctus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed vel lorem nec risus lacinia vehicula ac ultricies orci. Nulla rhoncus vehicula mollis. Vivamus porta nibh eget leo molestie, non convallis elit fermentum.</p>
<h1 id="zona3">Zona 3 <a href="#arriba">arriba (SIN scroll suave)</a></h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam efficitur elementum ornare. Nunc euismod tincidunt laoreet. Vestibulum id velit ac arcu mattis congue eget id sem. Morbi eget sollicitudin quam. Nulla lobortis mi eget magna luctus, eu elementum nunc rutrum. Sed tincidunt quam velit, fringilla vulputate urna sollicitudin in. Duis rhoncus viverra risus, at molestie mauris. Proin maximus consequat erat, eu maximus arcu dapibus ac. Quisque eu tristique nunc, in ultricies magna. Nullam mattis viverra justo vitae rutrum. Morbi vitae egestas justo, vel porta ex. Sed commodo malesuada cursus. Nullam maximus dolor a velit rutrum, eget auctor sem dapibus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam viverra lacinia lacus id hendrerit. Pellentesque molestie volutpat tortor a iaculis.<br/>Sed mattis aliquam erat viverra suscipit. Fusce tristique orci in arcu condimentum euismod. Nunc et rutrum justo, a scelerisque lectus. In varius metus eget vulputate pharetra. Proin in mi non augue ultricies faucibus in quis lorem. Ut consectetur sit amet eros id posuere. Praesent quis tortor ut massa hendrerit dignissim a vitae lectus. Aliquam commodo lacinia enim, ut aliquet eros elementum non. Morbi laoreet vulputate eros lacinia faucibus.<br/>Phasellus faucibus nunc sit amet tortor molestie, ac sagittis nunc blandit. Aliquam suscipit nec justo ut ornare. Praesent eget urna aliquam, vehicula nisi sit amet, fringilla lacus. Nulla pharetra purus blandit, tincidunt massa et, varius quam. Mauris non purus quam. Sed vel purus elementum, cursus nibh a, semper magna. Sed justo lectus, efficitur id risus aliquam, hendrerit semper justo. Quisque hendrerit convallis sapien. Cras hendrerit ac neque quis suscipit. Sed aliquam erat quis elit tincidunt, quis commodo dui ornare. Vivamus bibendum ligula nisl, ut sollicitudin elit convallis eu.<br/>Aenean mollis ullamcorper mollis. Proin dapibus id libero mollis egestas. Morbi tincidunt mattis pulvinar. Duis ut lorem a ante consectetur malesuada. Quisque placerat eros non ex efficitur cursus. Vivamus elit mi, venenatis eu purus vitae, lacinia laoreet elit. Nullam sapien elit, sodales at odio vel, sagittis vestibulum arcu. Duis at ipsum dolor. Fusce dictum eros vel luctus posuere. Phasellus blandit ante vel leo pulvinar, a hendrerit felis viverra. Morbi elit mi, sollicitudin sit amet ante sit amet, fringilla hendrerit quam.<br/>Cras porta fermentum diam, in pretium purus volutpat lacinia. Cras id elementum ante. Sed ultricies est quis odio ultrices luctus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed vel lorem nec risus lacinia vehicula ac ultricies orci. Nulla rhoncus vehicula mollis. Vivamus porta nibh eget leo molestie, non convallis elit fermentum.</p>
```